get_next_line function memory leaks (c)
The tester I am using shows that there are leaks all over the place, for instance with the memory allocated by ft_strdup.
When i go up the chain of functions I am under the impression that in any scenario ft_strdup is called, the result will be returned by each function until the end of get_next_line without any opportunity to free it.
char    *get_next_line(int fd)
    {
        static char *leftover;
        char        *next_line;

    if (BUFFER_SIZE <= 0 || !fd)
        return (NULL);
    if (!leftover)
        leftover = ft_read_from_file(fd, leftover);
    if (!leftover)
        return (NULL);
    next_line = ft_find_line(leftover);
    leftover = ft_strchr(leftover, '\n');
    if (leftover)
        leftover++;
    return (next_line);
}

char    *ft_read_from_file(int fd, char *leftover)
{
    char        *buffer;
    long long   bytes_read;

    buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * (BUFFER_SIZE + 1));
    if (!buffer)
        return (NULL);
    bytes_read = read(fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
    if (bytes_read < 1)
    {
        free(buffer);
        return (NULL);
    }
    else
        buffer[bytes_read] = '\0';
    leftover = ft_strjoin(leftover, buffer);
    free(buffer);
    return (leftover);
}

char    *ft_find_line(char *leftover)
{
    char    *str;
    int     i;
    int     j;

    j = 0;
    i = 0;
    while (leftover[i] != '\n' && leftover[i])
        i++;
    str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (i + 2));
    while (i > j)
    {
        str[j] = leftover[j];
        j++;
    }
    if (leftover[j] == '\n')
    {
        str[j] = leftover[j];
        j++;
    }
    str[j] = '\0';
    return (str);
}

char    *ft_strchr(const char *s, int c)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (s[i] && s[i] != (char)c && i < BUFFER_SIZE)
        i++;
    if (s[i] == (char)c)
        return ((char *)&s[i]);
    return ((void *)0);
}

char    *ft_strjoin(char const *s1, char const *s2)
{
    int     i;
    int     j;
    char    *str;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    if (!s1 && !s2)
        return (NULL);
    if (!s1)
        return (ft_strdup(s2));
    str = malloc((ft_strlen(s1) + ft_strlen(s2) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    if (str == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    while (s1[i])
    {
        str[j++] = s1[i++];
    }
    i = 0;
    while (s2[i])
    {
        str[j++] = s2[i++];
    }
    str[j] = '\0';
    return (str);
}

char    *ft_strdup(const char *s1)
{
    int     i;
    int     size;
    char    *ptr;

    i = 0;
    size = ft_strlen(s1);
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(char) * size + 1);
    if (ptr == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    while (s1[i])
    {
        ptr[i] = s1[i];
        i++;
    }
    ptr[i] = '\0';
    return (ptr);
}

int ft_strlen(const char *str)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i])
        i++;
    return (i);
}


The ft_read_from_file function allocates memory and return it. Then get_next_line will modify the pointer to the memory that ft_read_from_file returned, making you loose the original pointer. So you can no longer pass it to the free function to release the allocated memory.

You don’t want to perpetrate this design. Have the caller supply the buffer, and don’t do any memory allocation at all.

… which will also solve the thread non-safety problem your present code and design have.

You malloc() a string in ft_read_from_file() and you use strchr() with the malloc ptr.
Here a minimal example :
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        char * ptr;

        ptr = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
        strcpy(ptr, "test");

        printf("%p\n", ptr);
        ptr = strchr(ptr, 's');
        printf("%p\n", ptr);
        free(ptr); // free(): invalid pointer
        return (0);
}

Also why if (BUFFER_SIZE <= 0 || !fd) ?
0 is a valid file descriptor and you probably need to handle it.
Also is not really a good way to check the BUFFER_SIZE.
Here another way :
# if BUFFER_SIZE <= 0
#  error "BUFFER_SIZE can't be <= 0"
# endif   

